# Silverlight SaveFileDialog - set Default File Name

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, savefiledialog

I am currently reading a stream from a URL. And saving this as a file on the client.
I know that Silverlight 4 does not support the Default File Name on the SaveFileDialog.

Has anyone out there found a workaround or some way to inject the FileName into the Stream?

Any workaround would be great to set the file name.

Code:

```
    public void ClientOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       using (var file = Save.OpenFile())
       {
           CopyStream(e.Result, file);
       } 
    }

    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This probably wont be much of a help now, but Silverlight 5 SaveFileDialog supports default filename, so when its released it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.GetType().GetMethod("set_DefaultFileName").Invoke(dialog, new object[] { "FileName.ext" });
```

Works for me

Comment: That worked for me without changing the silverlight version. THanks gates (hope you are the real one ;-))

Comment: I have a security warning when I try to do this on Silverlight 4. Is it something expected?